# Convert SQL with nested queries to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent, backend

I need to convert this query that I got from Access to an Laravel eloquent for my remake database project, and this is what i did but i haven't the same result with the origin sql thanks.

```
    SELECT T_Sites.Code_Region, T_Sites.Nom_Site, T_CLM.N_CLM, T_Port.N_Port,
        T_Vlan.IP_Vlan, T_Ref_Vlan.Id_Referentiel, T_Ref_Vlan.Nom_Vlan,
        T_Vlan.Dt_Creat, T_Vlan.Id_Vlan, T_Vlan.IP_HSRP, T_Vlan.IP_SousReseaux,
        T_CLM.Id_CLM, T_Vlan.Masque
    FROM (T_CLM 
        INNER JOIN (
            (T_Port INNER JOIN T_Vlan ON T_Port.Id_Port = T_Vlan.Id_Port)
            LEFT JOIN T_Ref_Vlan ON T_Vlan.Id_Referentiel = T_Ref_Vlan.Id_Referentiel
        )
        ON T_CLM.Id_CLM = T_Port.Id_CLM)
        INNER JOIN T_Sites ON T_CLM.Id_Site = T_Sites.Id_Site
    ORDER BY T_CLM.Id_CLM DESC
    WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION;
// what i did
    $SuiviVlan = DB::table('T_CLM')
                ->join('T_Sites', 'T_CLM.Id_Site', '=', 'T_Sites.Id_Site')
                ->join('T_Port', 'T_CLM.Id_CLM' , '=', 'T_Port.Id_CLM')
                ->join('T_Vlan', 'T_Vlan.Id_Port', '=', 'T_Port.Id_Port')
                ->leftjoin('T_Ref_Vlan', 'T_Ref_Vlan.Id_Referentiel', '=', 'T_Vlan.Id_Referentiel')
                ->select('T_Sites.Code_Region','T_Sites.Nom_Site','T_CLM.N_CLM','T_Port.N_Port','T_Vlan.IP_Vlan',
                'T_Ref_Vlan.Id_Referentiel', 'T_Ref_Vlan.Nom_Vlan', 'T_Vlan.Dt_Creat', 'T_Vlan.Id_Vlan', 'T_Vlan.IP_HSRP', 
                'T_Vlan.IP_SousReseaux', 'T_CLM.Id_CLM', 'T_Vlan.Masque')
                ->orderBy('T_CLM.Id_CLM', 'desc')
                
                ->get();
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
// It was the correct laravel eloquent , thanks btw for help.
$SuiviVlan = DB::table('T_CLM')
            ->join('T_Sites', 'T_CLM.Id_Site', '=', 'T_Sites.Id_Site')
            ->join('T_Port', 'T_CLM.Id_CLM' , '=', 'T_Port.Id_CLM')
            ->join('T_Vlan', 'T_Vlan.Id_Port', '=', 'T_Port.Id_Port')
            ->leftjoin('T_Ref_Vlan', 'T_Ref_Vlan.Id_Referentiel', '=', 'T_Vlan.Id_Referentiel')
            ->select('T_Sites.Code_Region','T_Sites.Nom_Site','T_CLM.N_CLM','T_Port.N_Port','T_Vlan.IP_Vlan',
            'T_Ref_Vlan.Id_Referentiel', 'T_Ref_Vlan.Nom_Vlan', 'T_Vlan.Dt_Creat', 'T_Vlan.Id_Vlan', 'T_Vlan.IP_HSRP', 
            'T_Vlan.IP_SousReseaux', 'T_CLM.Id_CLM', 'T_Vlan.Masque')
            ->orderBy('T_CLM.Id_CLM', 'desc')
            
            ->get();
```